# R Outlier Indices Wrong

Tags: r, outliers

I am plotting the model diagnostic plots for leverage vs residual and seeing outlier labels that are for indices larger than my dataframe length.

I have a dataframe with 3066 obs. When I build my model, due to missing data, there are 2237 remaining obs.

```
cooksd<-cooks.distance(mod1)
length(cooksd) # is correct
```

But I have named entries in cooksd that refer to larger indices, ex:

```
cooksd["3131"]
```

How do I map the named entries in cooks distance plot and vector back to actual indices of the data?

[image]

Comment: can you share your data or a subset so it can be reproduced?

Comment: Interesting. When I save the data to csv and reload, the indices are correctly displayed. I'm working in RStudio Version 1.2.1335 for Mac.

Comment: My starting csv has an id column with duplicate entries. I'm deleting them using df<-df[unique(df$id),] . Then it seems I have to save as csv and reload the data for the indices to be properly reset.

Comment: the cooks is returning the row name and not the actual index/row number. If you want to reset your `row.names` you could do something like `row.names(df) <- 1:nrow(df)` so you don't have to keep reloading your data. or do something like `df[row.names(df)==3131,]` will also return that row

Comment: This does solve the problem thanks Mike. But it is very unexpected and unfortunate behaviour.

Comment: no problem. If you do not like that behavior you can use dplyr/tibbles and that will reset row.names when you filter data. check out the difference between these two dataframes and the `row.names`,  `iris2 <- iris[iris$Species != "setosa",];

iris3 <- filter(iris, Species != "setosa")

iris4 <- tibble::as_tibble(iris2)`